# Get Records in Order of conditions in where in clause

Tags: mysql

How do you get the result from database in the order of conditions in "where in" clause in mysql?

e.g:

table

```
id name
1 | riz
2 | irf
3 | far
4 | zab
5 | yas
```

i want my data in the order of conditions put in where in clause...?

```
select * from foo where id in (2,3,4,1,5);
```

eg.

```
id  name
2 | irf
3 | far
4 | zab
1 | riz
5 | yas
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Use :

```
select * from foo where id IN(2,3,4,1,5) order by FIND_IN_SET(id, '2,3,4,1,5');
```

It will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  foo 
where id in (2,3,4,1,5);
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET( id, '2,3,4,1,5' )
```

Here is the reference [ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 1):

You can provide each id as a different sorting case.

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE
  id IN(2,3,4,1,5)
ORDER BY
  id = 2 DESC,
  id = 3 DESC,
  id = 4 DESC,
  id = 1 DESC,
  id = 5 DESC
```